# How could I begin this proof in group theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

The question asks to show that the following combination of the set and the binary operation is a group.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the set $\Gamma_n = \{\xi^k : k = 0, 1, ..., n - 1\}$, where $\xi = e^{{2}{\pi}{i}/n} = \cos({2}{\pi}/n) + i\sin({2}{\pi}/n)$, and the multiplication of complex numbers.

I am already familiar with the four axioms that are required to be met for a group to exist:

1. Closure
2. Associativity
3. Identity
4. Inverse

Any hints to how I could start with the first axiom would be sincerely appreciated.

Kindest regards

Comment: Take two numbers of that form, say $\xi$ and $\zeta$, multiply them together and see whether the result is again in that form. Associativity and identity are (almost) automatic. I’ll leave it to you to use your previous method to show that every number of your form has its inverse also in that form.

Comment: Geometrically the points on the unit circle in the complex plane form the group of rotations under complex multiplication. This means the $n$-th roots of unity are a regular $n$-gon in the complex plane and they will form a finite cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For proving closure, note that $\Gamma_n = \{ z \in \mathbb C : z^n =1 \}$.

Therefore, if $z,w \in \Gamma_n$, then $(zw)^n = z^n w^n = 1$ and so $zw  \in \Gamma_n$.

This characterization of $\Gamma_n$ is also useful for checking the other axioms.

Answer (score 0):

For closure, any product $\xi^l\cdot\xi^k=\xi^{k+l}=\xi^{k+l\bmod n}$ is in $\Gamma_n$ again.

You can reduce the exponent $\bmod n$, because $\xi^n=1$.

Comment: Thank you, though I am a little confused about where the mod n came from after k + l?

Comment: You're certainly welcome.  Play around with it a little.  This is a basic fact.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that $\Gamma_n\le \Bbb C^*$.

Clearly, $\Gamma_n\subseteq \Bbb C^*$.

Since $\xi^0=1\in\Gamma_n$, $\Gamma_n\neq \varnothing$.

Let $\xi^r,\xi^s\in \Gamma_n$. Then $$\xi^r(\xi^{s})^{-1}=\xi^r\xi^{-s}=\xi^{r-s}\in\Gamma_n,$$ taking $r-s$ modulo $n$ if necessary.

Hence $\Gamma_n\le \Bbb C^*$ by the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

Hence $\Gamma_n$ is a group under multiplication, since each subgroup of a group is itself a group.